# How to send form value to api with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a doubt. How to send form values to the API? I have tried below jQuery code but it's not working. I have checked with alert messages the value that is passed. If you have any methods please let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".bttn").click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {};

    data['no'] = $('#id_Ticket_no').val();
    alert(data['no']);
    data['Ticket_Name'] = $('#id_Ticket_Name').val();
    alert(data['Ticket_Name']);
    data['priority'] = $('.select :selected').val();
    alert(data['priority']);

    data['status'] = $('.textinputstatus').val();
    alert(data['status']);

    data['Description'] = $('#id_Description').val();
    alert(data['Description']);
    data['time'] = $('#id_Ticket_Time').val();
    alert(data['time']);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://13.232.41.131/tickets/',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      success: function (callback) {
        console.log("Add response: " + JSON.stringify(callback));
        alert(callback.response);
      },
      error: function () {
        $(this).html("error!");
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: but i show below out in console

Comment: Add response: {"id":39,"no":"none","Ticket_Name":"default name","priority":"LOW","status":"uncleared","Description":null,"time":null}

Comment: sir i need below out put:
Add response: {"no":"1","Ticket_Name":"2","priority":"MEDIUM","status":"3","Description":"4","time":"5"}
    
currently show below out put, how to solve.
Add response: {"id":49,"no":"none","Ticket_Name":"default name","priority":"LOW","status":"uncleared","Description":null,"time":null}

Comment: currently show below out put, how to solve
    Add response: {"id":49,"no":"none","Ticket_Name":"default name","priority":"LOW","status":"uncleared","Description":null,"time":null}

Comment: which side  problem sir, API or my code. please explain. how to solve this issue. i need data send to API

Comment: sir data sent but not add in api. The console only show default values,(ex.null, null, null).Not show my input box values.
All values are null. please see below console error. 

Add response: {"id":54,"no":"none","Ticket_Name":"default name","priority":"LOW","status":"uncleared","Description":null,"time":null}

Comment: Seems like problem is on server side. Data is received by server but you forgot to display values. Can you post your server side code.